# How to search in elasticsearch similar to mysql like . for example i have to search on name . Can anyone tell me the complete request

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
curl localhost:9200/posts/tweet/_search?pretty -d '{
"query" : {
     "fuzzy_like_this" : {

     "like_text" : "ajma"

                         }`
          }
}'
```

I am not getting how this is executing .

*** EDIT ***

i am getting some irrelevant result . i am getting 3 names in result ["jolly ajmani","mahammad jama","bashir  ahmad" and not getting why "bashir ahmad" is coming in result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are asking why it isn't executing or if this query will do a similar task to MySQLs `like`. Quoted from Elasticsearch - `"Fuzzy like this query find documents that are "like" provided text by running it against one or more fields"`.

Have a look at the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-query.html) regarding this type of query for more information.

Try this -

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy_like_this": {
      "like_text": "ajmani",
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "max_query_terms": 12 here . curl localhost:9200/mphrx/medicalobject/_search?pretty -d '{"fields":["name"],
"query" : {
    "fuzzy_like_this" : {
       "fields":["name"],
       "like_text" : "ajma","max_query_terms": 12
       
    }
  }
}'
and i am getting result [jolly ajmani,mahammad jama,bashir  ahmad]. i am not getting ...why bashir  ahmad is coming .

Comment: @ShauravKumar "The maximum number of query terms that will be included in any generated query. Defaults to 25."